# Create a button to execute a .bat or .exe

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm a newbie with Electron and JS.

I've searched for a solution to create a simple button which executes a `.bat` file or `.exe` file.

I've read this [article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/154/how-to-execute-an-exe-file-system-application-using-electron-framework) about using `child_process`.

However, It doesn't say how to "link" var to my button.

My code is written in `renderer.js`

Answer (score 3):

electron runs using nodejs therefore you could do something along the lines of:

```
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

    var runExe = function(){
       execFile('<your-name>.exe', function(err, data) {  
            console.log(err)
            console.log(data.toString());                       
        });  
    }
```

now call
`runExe()`
using your button and you should be good to go

for more info see here
[node js reference](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

so what happens is basically that we run a specified exe file using like you already said the nodejs `child_process` ... hope that helped

Comment: Ok i understand.
But in html, how to call function ?

Comment: Thanks you very much for the reply :)

Comment: you can simply use a basic onclick event, see this link for info
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp

Comment: Is Work, Thanks Gunnar Thoreson

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Now is work i post my solution for electron:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <!-- All of the Node.js APIs are available in this renderer process. -->
    We are using Node.js <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chromium <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
   <h1> A simple Javascript created button </h1>

     <button onclick="function()">Firefox 1</button>
     <button onclick="firefox()">Firefox 2</button>

    <script>
var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

function firefox(){
       execFile("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", function(err, data) {  
            console.log(err)
            console.log(data.toString());                       
        });  
    }

  // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js')
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```